# failed with error code 1 using pip3 install windows

Tags: python, command

Trying to install turbodbc using

```
pip3 install turbodbc
```

and

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/blue-yonder/turbodbc.git
```

Both times, however, get this error:

```
"failed with error code 1"
```

Not sure how to get around this? Tried running as admin as well

```
 choco install turbodbc
```

But get " turbodbc - turbodbc not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed."

Here is full error:

```
Command "c:\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\thoma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-
4fw5vp_n\\turbodbc\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
0asz2meo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
build-4fw5vp_n\turbodbc\
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual error output instead of just the return code? All `1` means is "there was some error at some point", which isn't very useful.

Comment: Also, did you check the [install requirements](http://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/getting_started.html#windows)? Are you running Python 3.5 or 3.6, and do you have MSVS 2015 Update 3 Redistributable, 64 bit installed?

Comment: @abarnert thanks for getting back... will check requirements and post back in a sec

Comment: @abarnert added full error log

Answer (score 0):

Installing turbodbc directly from the GitHub repository is not possible at the moment; you need to use the package that was uploaded to PyPi. Please check that you are using Python 3.5 or 3.6, only for these version of Python binary releases are available for Windows.

You can also try to use the [conda environment](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/turbodbc), turbodbc conda packages are available for Python 3.5 and 3.6 as well.